# MySQL - How to take records based on a particular sequence

Tags: mysql

I would like to extract a number of records on a table based on a sequence e.g. n x 4. Which would mean I would need 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, etc...

Reading through the closest I found to what I'm looking for is:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID LIMIT n-1,1
```

I would like to see if it is possible to be done using just one query.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then `ROW_NUMBER` can be used here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) - 1 rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn MOD 4 = 0
ORDER BY ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `mod = 0`

```
select * from table where ID mod 4 = 0;
```

If you have your PK as integer or rowID you can simply use above query.
or else have to count manually without using row_number.

query in elaborate,

```
select * from (SELECT t.*, 
       @rowid := @rowid + 1 AS ID
  FROM TABLE t, 
       (SELECT @rowid := 0) dummy) A where A.ID mod 4 = 0;
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i gave a syntax. now i modified .. ROW_NUMBER() wasn't there in all version.. as you mentioned mysql 8+ .. so i am done with row_count myself

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of MOD function, it checks with the remainder after division of two values.
So accordingly your query will go as follows

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE ID MOD 4 = 0  ORDER BY ID
```